# Registration form not working in Chrome an mobile

Tags: php, mysql, forms, google-chrome

I'm a computing student and I'm working on a Virtual Learning Environment system for my dissertation.
I have a problem with registering new users. If I use it in Firefox, everything is ok, but if I try Chrome - I get just an empty record in my database. A friend of mine also tried it on his smartphone and it didn't work as well.

Here's my form code:

```
<form id="register_form" method="post" action="register.php" enctype="plain/text">
<fieldset class="reg1">
    <h2>Student registration form</h2>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="Student_id">Student id*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Student_id" id="Student_id" size="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
        <label for="Title">Title:</label>
        <select name="Title" id="Title">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="First_name">First name*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="First_name" id="First_name" size="40" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="Middle_name">Middle name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Middle_name" id="Middle_name" size="40" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="Last_name">Surname*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Last_name" id="Last_name" size="40" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="bDay">Date of birth*: &nbsp;</label>
            Day: <input type="text" name="bDay" id="bDay" size="3" /> Month: <input type="text" name="bMonth" id="bMonth" size="3" /> Year: <input type="text" name="bYear" id="bYear" size="5" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="gender">Gender*:&nbsp;</label>
            <label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" />
            <label for="Female">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="email">Email*:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="40" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="Town">Town:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Town" id="Town" size="40" />
        </div>
        <div class="line">
            <label for="password">Password*:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="40" /></p>

        <div class="line">
            <label for="cpassword2">Re-enter your password*:</label>
            <input type="password" name="cpassword2" id="cpassword2" size="40" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="line2">
        <button type="submit">Register</button><button type="reset">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here's the PHP script:

```
<?php
$student_id = $_POST['Student_id'];
$title = $_POST['Title'];
$firstName = $_POST['First_name'];
$middleName = $_POST['Middle_name'];
$lastName = $_POST['Last_name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$bDay = $_POST['bDay'];
$bMonth = $_POST['bMonth'];
$bYear = $_POST['bYear'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$town = $_POST['Town'];

    $encpassword=md5($cpassword);

      // CONNECT TO DATABASE
      $link = mysql_connect ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "u", "p");
      mysql_select_db ("XXX") or die("Database error: cannot connect to the database". mysql_error());

$query="SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Student_id='$student_id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
print "<h2>Student with the ID <i>$student_id</i> already exists. Please return to the <a href='register.html'>Register</a> page and provide correct data.</h2>";
}
else {
        $query = "insert into Student (Student_id, Student_firstName, Student_middleName, Student_surname, DOB, Title, Email, Password, Town, Student_pic) 
                values ('$student_id','$firstName', '$middleName', '$lastName', '$bYear-$bMonth-$bDay', '$title', '$email', '$encpassword', '$town', '$student_pic')";
        $result = mysql_query ($query);

    print "<h2>$firstName $lastName has been succesfully registered!</h2><br/><h3>Return to the <a href='index.html'>login page</a>.</h3>";
    }
?>
```

I have no clue what's going on. I've heard that using &nbsp can cause problems in Chrome, but I also have &nbsp in my logging script, which works fine in Chrome. Did anyone have the same problem?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome seems to dislike the `enctype='text/plain'` on the form tag.  Remove it and it should work.

Seems like someone even filed a bug report about it: [bug 1](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73979) and [bug 2](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45174)

Comment: I've just done that, but it doesn't help :/ I've also checked the website in IE and it works correctly. But Chrome still has a problem :/ Any other ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: No other ideas, sorry - with `enctype` my test site didn't work in Chrome, but removing it fixed the issue entirely.

Comment: Surprisingly it started to work :) Seems like in needed more time :D that's the kind of thing I will never understand about computers :) But anyway, wielkie dzięki za pomoc ;)

Answer (score 0):

- The enctype tag is fully supported by
  Chrome and it is absolutely
  unnecessary to remove this.

  - No changes required in HTML file.
  - I have found some semantic errors in
    your PHP file which is what prevented
    it from working. They are:

Your code: `$gender = $_POST['Gender'];`

The form in the HTML file posts gender (with a lowercase "g" not Gender with an uppercase "G").

Corrected code: `$gender = $_POST['gender'];`

Your code: `$encpassword=md5($_POST['cpassword']);`

Again the form does not post a cpassword entity. I don't know if you intend to retrieve the password from the first password box or the second (verification) password box. However, as you're posting both to the PHP page, the corrected code would be either

`$encpassword=md5($_POST['password']);`

OR

`$encpassword=md5($_POST['cpassword2']);`

You only need one, and either will work.

In the SQL insert query, you are passing the value of `$student_pic` which you have not declared prior to this. Note that your HTML page does not post a value that would be intended for this type of variable either. Declare the variable `$student_pic` and pass a value into it before passing its value through an SQL insert statement.

With the above changes, there are no issues, well I didn't come across any. I also created a database and tried, all works.

Here is the corrected code:

```
<?php
$student_id = $_POST['Student_id'];
$title = $_POST['Title'];
$firstName = $_POST['First_name'];
$middleName = $_POST['Middle_name'];
$lastName = $_POST['Last_name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$bDay = $_POST['bDay'];
$bMonth = $_POST['bMonth'];
$bYear = $_POST['bYear'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$town = $_POST['Town'];
$student_pic = 'test';

    $encpassword=md5($_POST['password']);

      // CONNECT TO DATABASE
      $link = mysql_connect ("localhost", "testU", "testP");
      mysql_select_db ("testdb") or die("Database error: cannot connect to the database". mysql_error());

$query="SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Student_id='$student_id'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
print "<h2>Student with the ID <i>$student_id</i> already exists. Please return to the <a href='register.html'>Register</a> page and provide correct data.</h2>";
}
else {
        $query = "insert into Student (Student_id, Student_firstName, Student_middleName, Student_surname, DOB, Title, Email, Password, Town, Student_pic) 
                values ('$student_id','$firstName', '$middleName', '$lastName', '$bYear-$bMonth-$bDay', '$title', '$email', '$encpassword', '$town', '$student_pic')";
        $result = mysql_query ($query);

    print "<h2>$firstName $lastName has been succesfully registered!</h2><br/><h3>Return to the <a href='alex.html'>login page</a>.</h3>";
    }
?>
```

Regards

Comment: Don't look at PHP - I removed some bits of code right here, so that's why little things didn't match. The original PHP code is correct - it works in both Firefox and IE, so this is not a server-side problem. There's something wrong with Chrome.

Comment: I've just came across this discussion on Google Chrome Help forums:http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5baadfc42864bbf9&hl=en
Apparently most of people have a problem with forms and empty POST variables... :/

Comment: And BTW - it stopped working again. I don't have a clue what's going on. Yesterday I tested it and it worked. Today I tried again and the problem returned...

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved it! Following the suggestions on Google Chrome forums: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5baadfc42864bbf9&hl=en

I used JavaScript to first detect the browser and if it's Chrome then submit it in a new tab. Voila!

Here's the code if someone needs it:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function checkBrowser(){
        var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
        var verOffset;

        // In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
        if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
             submitForm('_newtab');
        }

        else{ submitForm('_self');}
    }

function submitForm(targetForm){
    document.register_form.target=targetForm;
    document.register_form.submit();
}
</script>
```

And of course you need to add onclick="javascript:checkBrowser()" to the button in your form.
Seems to work well - I hope this won't change :)

Thanks everyone for help!